# static_assert not evaluated in template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code to determine if the template type has foo():

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_foo : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_foo<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().foo()) > > : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
void has_foo_f(){
    static_assert(has_foo<T>::value, "Type does not have foo()."); 
}
```

Then I have the `bar` function that takes a template parameter with `foo`:

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(has_foo_f<T>())>
void bar(){}
```

In the main file, I have a fail case:

```
//Foo does not implement foo(). It should fail!
template<typename T>
class Foo{};

int main()
{
    has_foo_f<Foo<int>>(); //This line fail
    bar<Foo<int>>();       //This line does not fail
}
```

When I call `has_foo_f` directly, the compiler gives me static assertion error, which is correct.
However when I call `bar<Foo<int>>`, the compiler successfully compiled it without error.

Why does this happen? Why is the static_assert not evaluated? I understand `decltype` does not need to evaluate `static_assert` to get the type info, but isn't `static_assert` always evaluated at compile time?

Comment: Doesn't seem like `decltype(has_foo_f<T>())` actually instantiates `has_foo_f`. I'm not sure if it's expected to or not though. Intuitively, it's clear the return type of `has_foo_f` is `void` without having to instantiate it. What happens if you change the return type to `auto`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operand of `decltype` is not evaluated and therefore does not require function definition to exist (or return type being complete) while function template is instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist. So you need to instantiate function template for check inside of function body to take place:

```
template<typename T, auto Dummy = &has_foo_f<T>>
void bar(){}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a documentation about this requirement?

Comment: @texasbruce Operand of `decltype` is not evaluated and does not require function definition to exist (or return type being complete) while function template is instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist.

Comment: I guess that limits the use case of static_assert by a lot. I thought it can somehow replace `std::enable_if` but now it seems like it cannot.

Comment: @texasbruce Maybe you are looking for [`concepts`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)?

Comment: I am, but unfortunately will have to wait for full compiler support. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @texasbruce There is also [Boost Concept Check Library (BCCL)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) that emulates concepts on current compilers